# Ruby On Rails 7 - Devise custom controller for registrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to include Authentication in my Ruby on Rails application. I am using Devise gem for the same. Below is the scenario.

- I have a User model which was created while I installed Devise.
- I have also created a new Controller named "Employees."
- Employees controller contains "New and Create" actions.

AIM: I want to use the Employees controller to create new Users instead of Devise Registrations controller.

Below is what I have done:

**Employees controller **

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController

  # GET /employees or /employees.json
  def index
   @employees = User.search_employee(params[:employeesearchfield])
  end

  # GET /employees/1 or /employees/1.json
  def show
   
   User.archive_employee(params[:id])
   @employee = User.find(params[:id])
   
  end

  # GET /employees/new
 ** def new
    @employee = User.new
  end
**
  def import 
    User.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to employees_url, notice: "Data imported."
  end

  def export
  @employees = User.all
  respond_to do |format|
     format.csv { send_data @employees.to_csv, filename: "employees-#{DateTime.now.strftime("%d%B%Y")}.csv"}
    end 
  end

  def delete_multiple
   @employees = User.find(params[:employee_ids])
   #Array objects can be deleted one by one only.
   @employees.each(&:destroy)
   redirect_to employees_url, notice: "Employee was successfully destroyed."
  end

  ** def create
    @employee = User.new(employee_params)
    if @employee.save
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Please check your email for confirmation instructions."
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end**

  private

  def employee_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :department, :employedon, :manager, :appraisalrating, :ctc, :empcategory, :empnumber, :post, :DOB, :personalemail, :contact, :officelocation, :workstyle, :gender, :companyname, :workshift, :address, :socialstatus, :employeepermanentillness, :phstatus, :bpay, :lastrevision, :appraisalcomments, :sup1, :sup2, :sup3, :sup4, :skillcategory, :estatus, :role)
  end

 
end
```

In Routes.rb file I have overridden the Devise route for registration controller as below:

**Routes file**

```
devise_for :employees, controllers: { registrations: "employees/new" }
```

**New User Form **

```
<div class = "container">


<%= form_with model: @employee, url: new_employee_path, method: :post do |f| %>
<div class = "container">
  
    <div class = "row">

        <p class="display-6">ACCOUNT INFORMATION</p>
                 <div class="form-group col-6">
                  <b>USERNAME:</b>
                 <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Enter username", class: 'form-content form-content w-100 p-1' %>
                 </div>

                 <div class="form-group col-6">
                 <b>DEFAULT PASSWORD</b>
                 <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Enter password (Minimum length: 6 characters)", class: 'form-content form-content w-100 p-1' %>
                 </div>
    </div>
```

**Question**: When I submit the form, I get a routing error. "**ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/employees/new"):"**

Expected Result: New User to be created.

Try: I am confused if the Employee Controller should inherit from Devise::RegistrationsController or not. I tried doing that but I get some error again. I am unable to understand the concept and wanted to request help.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a controller, you only need to do that: Declare the controller, not an action in it, nor a controller under its namespace.

This line

`devise_for :employees, controllers: { registrations: "employees/new" }`

Looks for controller:

`app/controllers/employees/new_controller.rb`

But you are not looking for it, are you? You need to change the line like this:

`devise_for :employees, controllers: { registrations: "employees" }`

and now you are targetting

`app/controllers/employees_controller.rb`

Comment: Yes this is the right approach ✅

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have made the changes. Also, Employee Controller now inherits from `Devise::RegistrationController`. But now I cannot even navigate to the Employee controller Index action. 

The following error appears: 

`Could not find devise mapping for path "/employees".

This may happen for two reasons:
1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example:
devise_scope :user do
get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
end`

Comment: You can't inherit a controller both from Application Controller and Devise controllers. So, you will no longer use resources for employess, but will add routes as suggested in the message you are getting